# Why did the Emperor remain motionless while Darth Vader threw him off the balcony?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

I'm wondering whether this was a movie sin but his body position seemed to stay the same? Also why didn't he stop using Force Lightning? He continued to use it even as he was falling down.

I'm also wondering whether Palpatine meant to electrocute Vader or was it just a coincidence (because he kept firing Force Lightning) .

It makes no sense as he just stood there allowing Vader to throw him.

Comment: The other question is specifically asking about using a lightsaber to prevent the fall, but the answers go into why he didn't try to stop it in any way.

Comment: @phantom42 - I agree. Although they cover the same event, the questions aren't duplicates.

Comment: @Richard - the answer from the linked one answers this one (and even has the same quote :)

Comment: @dvk - Much of the same quote but not quite the same answer.

Answer (score 18):

The [Official Novelisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi_%28novel%29) covers this event in a little more detail;

- **Why didn't he struggle?**

He did struggle, it's just that Vader is uncommonly strong and his struggles were largely ineffective.

- **Why did he carry on shooting out lightning?**

Palpatine was in extreme pain and doesn't seem to have been able to "turn off" his force-lightning. He was concentrating on the pain of being grabbed, then the shock of being hurled into the chasm.

- **Did he intentionally shock Vader?**

No. Vader got shocked because he grabbed someone who was using force-lightning. There doesn't seem to have been any intent on Palpatine's part to shock Vader.

> At that instant, Vader sprang up and grabbed the Emperor from behind,
>   pinning Palpatine’s upper arms to his torso. Weaker than he’d ever
>   been, Vader had lain still these last few minutes, focusing his every
>   fiber of being on this one, concentrated act - the only action
>   possible; his last, if he failed. Ignoring pain, ignoring his shame
>   and his weaknesses, ignoring the bone-crushing noise in his head, he
>   focused solely and sightlessly on his will - his will to defeat the
>   evil embodied in the Emperor.
>
> **Palpatine struggled in the grip of Vader’s unfeeling embrace, his
>   hands still shooting bolts of malign energy out in all directions. In
>   his wild flailing, the lightning ripped across the room, tearing into
>   Vader. The Dark Lord fell again, electric currents crackling down his
>   helmet, over his cape, into his heart.**

Answer (score -5):

Darth Vader uses is force strength, and can also control the  emperors mind if you really want to because of the high level force he possesses

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that Vader could control the emperor's mind?