# Why does Emperor Palpatine die so easily?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, return-of-the-jedi

Something I have always wondered is the end of Return of a Jedi, it seems like the Emperor dies *really* easily.

It seems a bit strange that the emperor (presumably the most powerful Dark Jedi there is) fairly easily dies. He is force lightninging Luke for a lot longer than he takes to die himself from what looks like the same thing. He also is easily picked up and dumped overboard by a dying <s>Vader</s> Anakin Skywalker.

I can think of a few plausible explanations:

- He somehow started a feedback loop on himself with force lightning once Vader picked him up
- He fell into a reactor core (or something at the bottom of the shaft)
- Force lightning took a lot of his energy

Neither of these feel very satisfactory - are there either canons or legends answers to why and how the Emperor died so easily?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/81632/31936 or http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/74198/31936

Comment: Because he fell [31 miles](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Star_II) into a [hypermatter reactor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hypermatter_annihilator)?

Comment: @WadCheber he fell 31 miles really, _really_ fast then :)